# How to add --add-opens command to Jenkins

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, intellij-idea, pom.xml

Environment:
Intellij
JDK 17
Maven

When i run my project i faced this error: Caused by: **java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make field private final java.util.Map sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationInvocationHandler.memberValues accessible: module java.base does not "opens sun.reflect.annotation" to unnamed module @68267da0**

Code:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ywpiC.png)
f.setAccessible(true); **this line throws the error**

solution is to add this line **JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS=--add-opens=java.base/sun.reflect.annotation=ALL-UNNAMED**
to the runner configuration at Intellij see the photo: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oG90n.png) and it works

but now i need to pass this line **JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS=--add-opens=java.base/sun.reflect.annotation=ALL-UNNAMED** to the **Jenkins job**

as i run my project through Jenkins so need to pass this solution to it
so how to do it?

Comment: Where is the message comming from? Have you checked the built on plain command line without jenkins? Do you get the same error? Either you use old deps or old plugin... but without more information it's hard to say..

Comment: Be advised that code which attempts to manipulate private fields in sun.reflect.annotation may break in later Java versions, since under the rules of object-oriented encapsulation, private implementations are free to change as long as the public interface remains stable.  In other words: what you’re doing will eventually stop working.

Comment: That is not a solution. That is a temporary workaround until you fix it properly.

Comment: Field f;
        try {
            f = handler.getClass().getDeclaredField("memberValues");
            f.setAccessible(true); --> this line throws the error
            Map<String, Object> memberValues;}

Answer (score -1):

1. At jenkins home page click **Manage Jenkins** link.
2. Click on the  **Global Tool Configuration** link.
3. Go to **JDK section** and click **Add JDK** button.
4. Fill the Name field , Add the name of the JDK.
5. Add the JAVA_HOME path for JDK installation directory.
6. In the Java Options field, enter the **"--add-opens"** command.

Example -> **--add-opens java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED**

7. Finally click save button.